# Getting info of user off firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create an app on Android that stores user contact info.

When the user creates a "contact card" to send to another user, I'd like it to display things I stored when registering the user, name, year, number etc.

When I push, `firebase` creates a unique key, and when I create a `FirebaseUser` it creates a uid. for ease, I save the uid as part of the user structure.

I'm now attempting to access that user using the uid, unfortunately the uid is not the key.

So, I'm trying to query. 
I create a Firebaseuser

```
currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser.getUid.
```

then I try to query by

```
DatabaseReference ref = firebase.getinstance().getReference("user);
ref.orderByChild("Uid").equalto(currentUser.getUid());
```

Is this correct? after I try to add a single `valuelistener` to obtain the actual values inside this user. Unfortunately this crashes. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please attach logs

Comment: "I'm now attempting to access that user using the uid, unfortunately the uid is not the key" Instead of working around this problem, solve it. Storing a list of users under their uid is a common data model. Fix your data model, fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the user uid as the key to save the user info like this:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
User user = new User(name, email);
mDatabase.child("users").child(userUid).setValue(user);
```

Then you can get the user info like this

```
ValueEventListener userListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get User object and use the values to update the UI
        User user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting User failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mDatabase.child("users").child(userUid).addValueEventListener(userListener);
```

If this doesn't work, write the error log on the OP please ;)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know i could change the user's index :)